# Double query results in model.js

Tags: javascript, angular, model

This is my Query on my model.

```
function GetOrders(req, res) {
  pool.getConnection((error, conn) => {
        if (error) {
          conn.release();
          res.json({
            "code": 100,
            "status": "Error in connecting to the database"
          });
          return;
        }
        let query = `SELECT res_transaction_pending.trans_id,
         res_transaction_pending.order_status,
         res_menu.menu_id,
         res_menu.menu_name
         FROM res_transaction_pending
         LEFT JOIN res_menu ON res_menu.menu_id = res_transaction_pending.menu_id
         WHERE res_menu.deleted = 0
        `;
        conn.query(query, (error, results) => {
          if (error) throw error;
          conn.release();
          res.json(results);
        });
      }
```

**The result is right but I'm having double result**
Ive checked it on my HeidiSQL, ive copy pasted the query, and the result was right.

My HeidiSQL query checked image below:

[image]

as you see the result are four, but in the model Im having eight.

Comment: Please add some code for your model.js. How exactly is this issue related to Angular?

Comment: the code is above there.

Comment: I was asking about the Angular Code where you're getting 8 records instead of four. Also, what do you get when you hit this API via Postman? 4 records or 8 records. I'm assuming that this query is exposed as a REST API.